# D3 Force layout with on tick, but static node location

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

Using a **standard force layout** with node data that **does not have** an `x` or `y` position.

I want to take advantage of `force.on("tick", function())`'s final `x` and `y` position, but **do not want the crazy, bouncy animation** that comes with tick changing x and y position for **5,000+ nodes**.

Have tried calling `d.fixed = true` after it finishes. Basically stripping the initial animation because of on tick.

**Edit**: Have also tried the following [from Mike Bostock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667139):

```
force.start();
for (var i = n * n; i > 0; --i) force.tick();
force.stop();
```

But it hangs the page :(

Comment: You want something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667139)?

Comment: @Mark exactly, the only issue is:

    `force.start();
        for (var i = n * n; i > 0; --i) force.tick();
        force.stop();`

hangs the page :(

Comment: There is an on-going discussion about accelerating force layout calculations for a large number of nodes in issue [*#1519 Use something quicker than d3.timer for the force layout*](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/1519) on github. The good news is that the new d3-force module of D3 4.0 comes with direct support for the simulation of static force layouts. Mike Bostock set up a nice [Block](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/01ab2e85e8727d6529d20391c0fd9a16) doing this asynchronously by employing a Web Worker which won't hang the page and actually runs pretty fast for 1,000 nodes.